# How to repeat a model field in django with the help of jquery?

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models

models.py

```
class Medicine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

class Prescription(models.Model):
    prescribed_medicine = models.ManyToManyField(Medicine)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name= 
                               'doctor_id')
    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, 
                                 related_name= 'patient_id')
    chief_complaint = models.TextField('Chief Complaint', max_length=100, 
                                        default='')
    on_examination_notes = models.TextField('On Examination Notes', 
                                            max_length=200, default='')
    diagnosis = models.TextField('Diagnosis', max_length=200, default='')
```

views.py

```
class PrescriptionCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PrescriptionForm
    template_name= 'core/prescription_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.doctor_id = self.request.user.id
        obj.patient_id = self.kwargs['patient_id']
        return super(PrescriptionCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class PrescriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prescription
        fields = ('chief_complaint', 'on_examination_notes', 'diagnosis', 
                    'prescribed_medicine')
```

I am trying to create multiple instances of a form field of a model form, tried using formsets but they are not so clear to me.

What exactly i am trying to do is, when the doctor writes a prescription to patient, there should be 3 empty fields for prescribed_medicine, and an add More button to add some more empty fields for prescribed medicines along with an option to delete adjacent to medicine field.

Comment: if you click on the "Ask a Question" button and do not use the "?" in your Question, its probably not good. What is your Question? And please do not answer "How to do all that?".

Comment: @hansTheFranz made some edits suggested by you

Answer (score 1):

You just described django formset.

I recommend taking a look at [django dynamic formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) . Based on your model, it should be pretty simple to implement.
For more complex models, I recommend creating the jQuery part from scratch to prevent jQuery complications.